# Get difference between 2 images and normalise the result

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I want to get the difference between the two images and normalise the resulting array and scaled to fit [0,255].

I was trying the following:

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread("lko.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("jum.png")

cv2.subtract(img1, img2)
```

But I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this? How could I normalise the resulting array and scale to fit [0,255?]

Comment: you could multiply every value by 255 divided by the maximum value of that "difference array"

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define what you mean by the "difference between 2 images". It is important to notice that `cv2.subtract` performs saturation, which means that, if you images are in e.g. `np.uint8`, all negative values will be clipped to 0 (see more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817868/4228275)). Maybe that's not what you want. But let's say it **is** what you want. Then, you can do what [@Tilman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8269281/tilman-b-aka-nerdyyy) said in the comments (you need to subtract the min too, see below). If you do not understand why, more details can be seen in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/281164/164237). Basically, your code would be like this (I did it step-by-step so that you could understand):

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread("lko.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("jum.png")

diff = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)  # range [a, b]
diff = diff - np.min(diff)       # range [0, b-a]
diff /= np.max(diff)             # range [0, 1]
diff *= 255                      # range [0, 255]
```