# Why the subtraction difference?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I was trying to calculate similarity using MSE for the following images:

A: [image: A] B: [image: B] C: [image: C]

All the images are different but clearly the 1st & 3rd are the most similar. However, when I try to compute the MSE using numpy subtraction:

```
error = np.sum((imageA - imageB) ** 2)
error /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])
```

images A&B receive the smallest error (5.5 vs 7.7) which would be incorrect. However, if I convert the images to floats then do the subtraction

```
err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2)
err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])
```

I get the right answer with A&C having the smallest error (1607 vs 24422). What would be the reason for this? The [article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/) this method is from mentions its to avoid "modulus operations wrapping around" but I also used cv2.subtract which I [thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817037/opencv-image-subtraction-vs-numpy-subtraction/45817868) avoided that issue.

Comment: Looks like it'd be overflow or underflow to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough data to fully answer this question, but I believe this discrepancy is caused by a representation issue: probably your images are `uint8` type so the subtraction of those can cause problems of overflow.