Averaging an image and extracting a mask which is not expected
I'm doing a beginner practice project where I'd like to extract the changing features in an image. One way I've thought of doing this is taking the average of the video across all the frames (which should allow the colors to approach the background).
I'm using the Mall Dataset, so an example frame would be this image of people walking through a hallway in the mall:

For 2000 frames, if we average it, it should approach an image of the mall without the people, like this image which I got from doing so:
.
Here's the code for that (I haven't yet figured out how to clamp values between 0, 255 during the subtraction operation so ignore the white strip at the top):
img_names = sorted([os.path.join('mall_dataset/frames', f) for f in os.listdir('mall_dataset/frames')])[1:]
h, w, c = cv2.imread(img_names[0]).shape
accumulated = np.zeros((h, w, c), dtype=np.float64)
for fname in img_names:
  accumulated += cv2.imread(fname).astype(np.float64)
avg = accumulated / len(img_names)
avg = np.clip(avg, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8) - np.ones((h, w, c), dtype=np.uint8) * 5
plt.imshow(avg)

My thinking is that the output image should be the background, just slightly darker and the shadows on the floor glare should be a bit blurred. Thus, if I create a mask from thresholding one of the image frames subtract the average colors, the result should be some array that, when plotted, shows filled-in figures where the people are. Here's my implementation of that:
map = np.full((h, w), False)
diffset = np.full((h, w, c), 0)
img = cv2.imread('mall_dataset/frames/seq_000023.jpg')
for i in range(len(map)):
  for j in range(len(map[i])):
    cdiff = np.abs(img[i,j]-avg[i,j])
    diffset[i,j] = cdiff #diffset was just for debugging
    if (cdiff<250).all(): #250 is the threshold here
      map[i,j] = True
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(map * 255)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(avg)

However, the unexpected issue pops up here. Instead of showing filled-in people, the result is outlines of people. I'm not sure if this is some issue with what I'm doing (like for example (cdiff-250).all() is still relatively unknown to my beginner brain, so I'd like to know what you all think.
Edit: right after posting I realized I forgot to add in an image for the result that I'm confused about. Here's the image for convenience (and my lack of eloquent description):


What's the intended output in the case where img[i,j]-avg[i,j] doesn't fit into the range of a uint8? (In other words, what is intended to happen when img[i,j]-avg[i,j] is not in the range 0-255?)

I wasn't quite sure how to fix that, but uint8 seems to overflow upwards to the max range. My wish is to make it clamped to 0 so it wouldn't overflow but it didn't seem to mess anything up as it was just a black band on top so I decided to just ignore it.

What you're describing is called saturation. You can do it with opencv like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817037/opencv-image-subtraction-vs-numpy-subtraction More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic Alternatively you can cast to a wider dtype, do the math, then use clip().

Got it, thanks! That feels much better. Do you have any ideas about why the people are being outlined only? Could this be due to a similar arithmetic problem?

Use cv2.absdiff

Just curious though, is it expected to only have outlines if I just use subtraction without cv2.absdiff?
